# Angular2 Bind looped list of checkboxes to variable

Tags: angular

I have a simple array of objects to display some checkboxes like this:

```
excludeRecords = [
    {label: 'Full Mailing Address', value:'fullMailing', checked:false},
    {label: 'Full Office Address', value:'fullOffice', checked:false},
    {label: 'Email Address', value:'emailAddress', checked:false},
    {label: 'Phone #', value:'Phone #', checked: false},
];
get selectedRecords() {
    return this.excludeRecords.filter(opt=>opt.checked).map(opt=>opt.value);
}
```

I'm outputting them in the HTML template like this:

```
<div class="horizontalOptions">
    <label 
    class="horizontalOption"
    *ngFor="let choice of excludeRecords"
    >
        <input type="checkbox"
        [value]="choice.value"
        [(ngModel)]="choice.checked"
        >
        {{choice.label}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to access the `get selectedRecords()` part.

I tried this:

`{{excludeRecords.selectedRecords()}}`

I don't think that's the right syntax, I want to access it in both the template and in the component.ts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `*ngFor="let choice of selectedRecords` since it's a getter mean it's a property, you don't need `()`, it's not a function.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

you can store it in another variable:

```
myselectedRecords : any[];
get selectedRecords() {
    this.myselectedRecords = this.excludeRecords.filter(opt=>opt.checked).map(opt=>opt.value);
}
```

and use this variable on the template:

```
<label 
    class="horizontalOption"
    *ngFor="let choice of myselectedRecords"
    >
```

or make a service component to process the array ; anyway  you must store it in a a variable in your component.

Comment: what does the `any[]` do?

Comment: when I do that I get this error message:
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: setting a property that has only a getter

Comment: Or when I split out the methods I get a `duplicate identifier` error

Comment: i've updated my answer, new variable and function must to be different,    list: any[] , just make public the variable